# Why removing item from array of roles breaks when storing the array as a JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony

I have a Symfony 4 project with an user entity with "roles" array (in JSON in my database).

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json")
 */
private $roles = [];

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

    return array_unique($roles);
}

public function addRole($role)
{
    if (!in_array($role, $this->roles)) {
        array_push($this->roles, $role);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function hasRole($role)
{
    if (in_array($role, $this->roles)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function removeRole($role)
{
    if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
        unset($this->roles[array_search($role, $this->roles)]);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So, my `User` roles can be something like :

```
["ROLE_VALIDATEUR", "ROLE_SUPER_VALIDATEUR"]
```

[image]

But when I use my remove function to remove a role, like "ROLE_SUPER_VALIDATEUR" (so, after that, I've just the "ROLE_VALIDATEUR" role) sometimes, my roles array breaks like this:

```
{"1" : "ROLE_VALIDATEUR"}
```

[image]

What is the problem with my remove function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```php
$this->roles = array_values($this->roles);
```

right after this in your `removeRole($role)` method:

```php
unset($this->roles[array_search($role, $this->roles)]);
```

The problem is that `unset()` removes the array value, but it doesn't reindex the array. So are left with an array with no `0` index (in your example), and only a `1` index.

That's interpreted as an associative array when converted to JSON, instead of a plain indexed array.

By using `array_values()` you are rebuilding the indexed array that holds the roles for the user entity, and the property will be saved correctly in the DB.